# Load mingw-g++-generated symbols in IDA?

Tags: mingw, ida

Is there any way to load debug symbols created by MinGW g++ in IDA?
When I load the binary I have in IDA it doesn't appear to find anything useful, nor does attempting to load a strip --only-keep-debug file. Am I just missing something or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

MinGW symbols will be handled in 6.3.